# VBA: Passing values from array to range

Tags: vba, excel

This should be fairly straightforward. But for some reason I'm getting blank cells instead of the values from the array being passed into the cells.

```
redim rFin (2,1)
rfin (1,1) = "Bla1"
rfin (2,1) = "Bla2"

oSht1 = activesheet
lRow = 10

With oSht1
    .Range(.Cells(lRow1 + 1, 6), .Cells(lRow1 + 2, 6)) = rFin
End With
```

EDIT: Also tried with rFin having values from 0 to 1 instead of 1 to 2.

Comment: `ReDim rFin (1 To 2, 1 To 1)`

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
Option Base 1

Sub Main()
    ReDim rfin(2, 1)
    rfin(1, 1) = "Bla1"
    rfin(2, 1) = "Bla2"

    Set oSht1 = ActiveSheet
    lRow = 10

    With oSht1
        .Range(.Cells(lRow + 1, 6), .Cells(lRow + 2, 6)) = rfin
    End With
End Sub
```

The important thing is the `Option Base 1` because without it arrays start at 0.  Or this would work:

```
'default of Option Base 0

Sub Main()
    ReDim rfin(2, 1)
    rfin(0, 0) = "Bla1"
    rfin(1, 0) = "Bla2"

    Set oSht1 = ActiveSheet
    lRow = 10

    With oSht1
        .Range(.Cells(lRow + 1, 6), .Cells(lRow + 2, 6)) = rfin
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: oh... I didn't know that! I just found a workaround. I'll post it as an answer (although my workaround is not as elegant as your more effective solution)

Comment: btw, do you know if base 1 can be used with a single variant? (Instead of affecting all variants through the subs.)

Comment: Well, idk, using redim rFin(1 to 2,1) does not work for me (I end up with blank cells). My work around (using an empty range to make the variant match the range's format) allows me to use a single variant of this format (thus not having to change the variants and loops I had already set up).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: using an empty range to make the variant match the range's format, which allows me to use a single variant of this format (thus not having to change the variants and loops I had already set up).

```
oSht1 = activesheet
lRow = 10

With oSht1
    rFin = .Range(.Cells(lRow1 + 1, 6), .Cells(lRow1 + 2, 6))
End With

    rfin(1, 1) = "Bla1"
    rfin(2, 1) = "Bla2"

With oSht1
    .Range(.Cells(lRow1 + 1, 6), .Cells(lRow1 + 2, 6)) = rFin
End With
```

Not an elegant solution, but it does work. Just use an empty range.

Comment: That's a good solution to avoid having to worry about the base of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
oSht1.Cells(lRow1 + 1, 6).Resize(2) = [{"Bla1";"Bla2"}]
```

or even shorter

```
[F11:F12] = [{"Bla1";"Bla2"}]
```